# Automatically fill table with data inserted in the server

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Well i have this table created manually, i want that for every html document in the "Dinamico" case appears automatically in the table. Every time i have a new html page it should create a new "tr" element

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Esquema de MetaDados</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><a strong href="Templates/MetaDadosVideo/template_Video.html">Metadados Video</a></td>
        <td>Catalogação e arquivo de conteúdos de Videos de Concerto, entrevistas</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><a strong href="Templates/MetaDadosGráficos/template_gráficos.html">Metadados Materiais Gráficos</a></td>
        <td>Arquivo de Materias Gráficos Finais</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><a strong href="#">Metadados Porto 2001</a></td>
        <td>Conteudos da Porto 2001</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><a strong href="Templates/Dinamico/formD1.html">Metadados Dinamico</a></td>
        <td>Conteudos da Porto 2001</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Also when he choose a template the iframe with the "page.html" change to the user option selected. How can i achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html id="the">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../CSS/form.css">

</head><body style="background-color:white;">
<script>
     var Nome; // Nome do esquema 
    var Desc; // descrição do esquema
    var temas = []; // Nome dos temas do form
    var fields = []; // nr de campos
    var FL= []; // Nome do campo
    var TF =[]; // tipo do campo
    </script>

    <div>
<iframe src="../../Resources/logo-cm__.png" frameBorder="0" width="30%" height="80px" align="left" scrolling="mo"
/>
    </iframe>
</div>
<div>
<iframe src="../../Resources/title.png" frameBorder="0" width="60%" height="80px" align="center" scrolling="no" />
</iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe src="page.html" frameBorder="0" width="70%" height="600px" align="left" scrolling="no" />    
</iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe src="../../galeria/frame2_galeria.html" frameBorder="0" width="29%" height="600px" align="right" scrolling="yes" />    
</iframe>
</div>
<a onclick="this.href='data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,'+encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML)" href="#" download="page.html">Download Template</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean every time you upload a new html file? Question could use more specific details. Is confusing

Comment: yes every time a new html page is inserted in the case, the table fills automatic. Sry for not being clear enough

Comment: You need a server side language to read directories if that is what you want.

Comment: With php i can read the directory of the server? and do a search automatically? That every times it finds a html page does the echo as html link element.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Do the dynamic content all in php if that is what you have on server.

Comment: Do u have some sort of exemple cause this isn't really my beach

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like where u can create a dynamic table for each html and give the column of the table the name of the file. In the something put the path for each directory where the html file is stored

```
foreach (glob("omething*.htm") as $filename) {
              foreach(glob("Templates/Dinamico/*.txt") as $txtname){ 
               $fileH= basename($filename,".htm");  

            if($filename != "something.html"){ 
                echo'<tr>';
                echo'<td>';

                echo "<a name='".$fileH."'strong href='something.php?id=$fileH'>".$fileH."</a>";

                echo'</td>';
                echo'<td>';
                echo $txt;
                echo'</td>';
                echo'</tr>';
```